# 90's era robot horror/thiller movie opening with adults escaping a malfunctioning robot, leaving their baby in the crib

Tags: story-identification, movie

I was pretty young when my parents had a movie on, probably around 1993-96.

Opening scene of the movie is set in a modern suburban neighborhood at night, and there is a police cordon surrounding a house. The adults escaped, but left the baby in the crib. They seemed to need to escape because an yet-unseen robot had malfunctioned and was somehow threatening.

After that they said it was too scary for me and put me to bed. I frequently wonder what the movie was and want to see it now that I'm adult but no amount of googling has helped.

Comment: Hi there. If you can, please have a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. For instance - did you watch that in English, was it a translation? Could you perhaps ask your parents if they remember any more pplot details?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a feeling this is [Runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_(1984_American_film)) (1984).

The movie starts with a plague of household (and industrial) robots running wild. Tom Selleck's character has to go into a house after a couple flees one such malfunctioning robot and [I think] rescue a child in a crib - I'm just not sure about the child though.

The suburban neighborhood, police cordon, etc, are all spot on.

I did not make it very far into this movie before bailing, so I might be wrong.

But this trailer makes me more confident. At ~20 seconds in, you see Selleck getting ready to enter the house, and he says something about "the kid."

Comment: Good catch. The movie is [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzX6wxeneaY) (in poor quality, and cropped) and there's a baby to be heard at 11:50.

Comment: Dang, you guys are good! Thank you so much!